# Using Python subprocess to open Powershell causes encoding errors in stdout

Tags: python, powershell, character-encoding, subprocess

I'm trying to run a Powershell script from python and print the output, but the output contains special characters "é".

```
process = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',  'echo é'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(process.stdout.read().decode('cp1252'))
```

returns ","

```
process = subprocess.run(r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe echo é', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(process.stdout.decode('cp1252'))
```

returns ","

```
print(subprocess.check_output(r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe echo é').decode('cp1252'))
```

returns ","

Is there an alternate method other than subprocess, or maybe a different encoding I should be using?

UTF-8 gives an error for é but returns an "r" for ®. UTF-16-le gives the error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 2: truncated data".

Comment: For anyone else who is running into this issue I found a workaround (It works for my application but it isn't pretty). You can pipe the output to a text file using ">" and it will stay in UTF-16. Then you can read from the text file using "with open('file.txt', 'rb') as fp:" and decode the file using print(fp.read().decode('UTF-16')).

Comment: Just out of interest: what `bytes` do you get when not decoding? This should lead to the right encoding if that's the problem. edit: it's `b'\x82\r\n'`. Encoding *could* be [`cp437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or cp850 then. Find it in the [properties dialog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/how-to-change-default-code-page-of-powershell-console/m-p/2275773)

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, cp437 was able to decode. I did not try it originally because I read somewhere that powershell was UTF-16. cp1252 was tried because I used it in some other code and it worked. I'm doing more research into encodings now, but it was hard to know what to search for originally other than "what encoding does powershell use"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI,<sup>[1]</sup> uses the active console window's code page** to encode its stdout and stderr output, as reflected in the output from `chcp`, which by default is the legacy system locale's ***OEM* code page**, e.g. (expressed in Python terms) `cp437`.

By contrast, the code page you used - `cp1252` - is an *ANSI* code page.

- Note: ***Python* uses the system's *ANSI* code page** by default **for encoding *its* stdout and stderr output**, which, however, is ***nonstandard* behavior**: console applications are expected to use the current console's output code page, which is what `powershell.exe` does and which, as stated, is the system's *OEM* code page.

One option is to simply **query the console window for its active (output) code page via the WinAPI and use the encoding returned**:

```py
import subprocess
from ctypes import windll

# Get the console's (output) code page, which the PowerShell CLI
# uses to encode its output.
cp = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()

process = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe echo é', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Decode based on the active code page.
print(process.stdout.read().decode('cp' + str(cp)))
```

However, note that the OEM code page limits you to 256 characters; while `é` *can* be represented in [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), for instance, other Unicode characters, such as `€`, cannot.

Therefore the ***robust* option is to (temporarily) set the console output code page to `65001`, which is UTF-8**:

```py
import subprocess
from ctypes import windll

# Save the current console output code page and switch to 65001 (UTF-8)
previousCp = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)

process = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe echo é€', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Decode as UTF-8
print(process.stdout.read().decode('utf8'))

# Restore the previous output console code page.
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(previousCp)
```

Note:

- The above only ensures that the PowerShell child process emits UTF-8 and that its output is decoded as such inside the Python process, which is unrelated to what character encoding Python *itself* uses for its output streams.
- To **put Python v3.7+ itself in [Python UTF-8 Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode)**, which makes it decode input as UTF-8 and produce UTF-8 output, pass command-line option `-X utf8` or define environment variable `PYTHONUTF8` with a value of `1` *before* invocation.
- To additionally **make an interactive shell session use UTF-8** (use the `65001` code page) for the remainder of the session:

  - In a **`cmd.exe`** session:

    - `chcp 65001`
  - In a **PowerShell** session:

    - `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`
  - A **simpler alternative via a *one-time configuration step*** is to configure your system to **use UTF-8 *system-wide***, in which case both the OEM and the ANSI code pages are set to `65001`. However, this has **far-reaching consequences** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

---

<sup>[1] The same applies to [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the CLI of the modern [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition.</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed! (Some notes from other things I tried) "sys.getfilesystemencoding()", returns UTF-8. "subprocess.check_output("chcp 65001 | powershell \"echo é", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)" works for check_output, but I couldn't get it working for Popen, "chcp 65001" doesn't want to be passed as an arg.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @beneverest; a `chcp` solution _is_ possible, but it'll be slower, due to involving 2 `chcp` child processes (the second one to restore the original): `process = subprocess.Popen(f'chcp 65001 >NUL & powershell.exe echo é€ & chcp {previousCp} >NUL', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` - additionally, a display bug in Windows PowerShell causes the `chcp` call to switch the console to a raster font that cannot render `€`, for instance.